# How to structure the quantile() output in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

This should be pretty simple, but I'm struggling with, so I decided to find someone to help.

I'm trying to get the output of the `quantile()` function in a dataframe.

This is what I'm doing:

```
iris.groupby('Species')['SepalWidthCm'].quantile([.1, .2, .3, .4, .5, .6, .7, .8, .9])
```

This is what I get:

```
Species             
Iris-setosa      0.1    3.00
                 0.2    3.10
                 0.3    3.20
                 0.4    3.36
                 0.5    3.40
                 .
                 .
                 .
Iris-versicolor  0.1    2.30
                 0.2    2.50
                 .
                 .
                 .
```

But this is what I wanted:

```
Species             p1    p2    ...
Iris-Setosa         3.00  3.10  ...
Iris-versicolor     2.30  2.50  ...
```

Is there any easy way of getting this dataframe?

Comment: try `.unstack(level=1)` at the end

Comment: @ansev excellent! Thanks!